# SELECT INSERT script sql error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table product, product_sn

for every product have one or mutltiple sn ( serialNumber)
so lets imagine I ve product id = 11, productName = 'milk' I want copy all serialNumber from produt_sn into table product

```
declare table product (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    productName varchar(100),
    serialNumber BIGINT
)

declare table product_sn (
    serialNumber BIGINT
)


product_sn (
    867635017749586,
    867635017734984,
    867635017753893,
    867635017724894,
    867635017749727,
    867635017725289,
    867635017752739,
    867635017724761,
    867635017756193,
    867635017756268
)

declare @sn bigint
select @sn from product_sn
insert into product values (id,productName,@sn) ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @sn bigint
select @sn from product_sn
```

This will definitely throw an error here because you're attempting to select multiple rows into a single variable.

To correct that issue, try the following:

```
insert into product(serialnumber)
select serialnumber
from product_sn
```

Comment: what about id, productName ?

Comment: ID will be auto-generated by SQL Server and the table 'product_sn' does not have productname defined.  If you want to assign a static productname, alter the insert statement to include one.

Answer (score -1):

I am only guessing here since you haven't provided the actual error, but it seems you are trying to insert value to field which is defined as identity, well don't.

just write :

```
insert into product values (productName,@sn)
```